# Excel pivot different between previous year value

Tags: excel, date, pivot, difference

i'm using a pivot table and i'm trying to compare summed value of a month of two years.

![Example][1]

How can i add (using pivot methods) a column with the % difference between these any year-month and the month of the previous year?
note that i I can have more years.

Here is an example of the output of a row that i would like to obtain.
![enter image description here][2]

Comment: It would help a lot if you could include the desired output as an example.

Comment: What you want to accomplish can not be simply done with Pivot Tables. You will have to add a new manual column to the pivot table and set the formulas in it manually

Comment: Thanks But i could get it :):)

Comment: Please share your findings

Comment: Yes sorry i forgot it!
i added the sum field again, options and showed it as "% discordance from"  and set as base the field "years" and selected (previows). i'll post a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how the OP solved the issue:

[image]